Can I use REPLACE in a subquery in Snowflake?
I am trying to use a function that reads its string input parameter value from a table A and returns an output based on a match on a table B.
If the string in Table A contains a substring like a string a contained in Table B, then it returns the whole string in A with the substring a replaced by a substring b (also contained in Table B).
The function involves a REPLACE function within it, and this is causing an error "Unsupported subquery type cannot be evaluated". I am certain that the REPLACE function is the one causing trouble, because I have done this in the past and it works. It also works when the REPLACE is out of the equation.
I created a basic scenario to illustrate what I have done:
        --1) Creation of table the function reads from

        create or replace TABLE replace_table_test (
    
    
        substring_a VARCHAR(100),
    
        substring_b VARCHAR(100)
        );
    
        insert into replace_table_test  (substring_a, substring_b) values ('ado', 'ada');
    
        select * FROM replace_table_test;

    
        --2) Creation of the function

        CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION replace_test (field_value STRING)

        RETURNS STRING
        
        AS
        
        $$
        
          SELECT
        
          REPLACE(field_value, substring_a, substring_b)
                    
          FROM replace_table_test 
        
          WHERE 
        
                field_value ILIKE ('%' || substring_a || '%') 
        
        $$;

        -- testing the function outside a query, where it works

        SELECT replace_test('mantecado');
        SELECT replace_test('ado');
        SELECT replace_test('recado');

        --3) Creation of table with input values for the function

        create or replace TABLE to_replace_test (
    
        string_original VARCHAR(100)
        );
    
        insert into to_replace_test  (string_original) values ('mantecado');
        insert into to_replace_test  (string_original) values ('recado');
        insert into to_replace_test  (string_original) values ('pelado');
        
        select * FROM to_replace_test;

        --4) Testing the function within query (returns: Unsupported subquery type cannot be evaluated)

        SELECT 
            string_original,
            replace_test(string_original)
        FROM to_replace_test;

What I was expecting is a the table 'to_replace_test' with the values 'mantecada', 'recada' and 'pelada'.

From what you are asking it looks like you want the values updated in the table and could not find any update statement, just ry replacing your select with the update statement.

@Lucas Using UDTF: CREATE OR REPLACE  FUNCTION replace_test (field_value STRING) RETURNS TABLE(replaced_value STRING) AS $$ SELECT  REPLACE(field_value, substring_a, substring_b)  FROM replace_table_test WHERE field_value ILIKE ('%' || substring_a || '%') $$; and SELECT string_original, f.* FROM to_replace_test, TABLE (replace_test(to_replace_test.string_original)) AS f; Results

Hi @LukaszSzozda, this works, thanks. At least in this basic model. I'll try to translate this to the real model and see if it works. Please feel free to post this as an answer and I will validate it.

Checking my main function, I am already using a UDTF to begin with. The problem is that I created a second STRING function that passes the first to return comma-separated values. It is then, using that STRING function, that I cannot make it work. Do you think is possible to make it work using a STRING function?
